# Как выбрать нужный элемент со страницы при наличии таких же с одинаковым именем?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Суть в чем. Есть веб-страница, я хочу с помощью селениума выбрать поле для ввода. Сначала одно, потом второе. Но у них одинаковый класс, одинаковые div-ы. Как быть в этом случае? Пробовал указывать какой именно div мне нужен с помощью индекса [0] и [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR9G4.jpg) через xpath. Но это не работает, выдает ошибку.

```html
<div class="xdsoft_autocomplete" style="display: inline-block; width: 170px;">
<input data-id="" data-value="" type="text" class="nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input" 
value="" placeholder="Откуда?" style="font-size: 14.7px; 
background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" autocomplete="off"><div
```

Вот есть два таких "дива" и два таких же инпута, по каждому внутри каждого дива. Как выбрать первый, потом второй?

Приложил скрин. Все хранится в div id routers, в них два дива route typeaheaded, и в нем лежит input, который мне нужен

Мой код:

```
addr_to = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='routers']/input[contains(@class='nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input')]")
```

Выдает ошибку, хоть с индексом [0], хоть без него. Не могу понять что не так делаю

Comment: я бы предложил [find_element_by_css_selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) с использованием псевдоклассов (выбирать не индексами, а `first-child` или `nth-of-type` например)... имхо, восприятие css селекторов намного проще, нежели xpath, соответственно проще отладить.

Comment: Я считаю, правильно, что вы используете XPath, но вы нагородили)))

Comment: А можно второй <input> на показать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в своём XPath наворотили невероятный бутерброд, так ещё и по не существующим данным.
Давайте посмотрим что-же вы нагородили))):

1. У вашего `<div>` элемента нет атрибута `id`, но вы пытаетесь его по нему найти:

`<div class="xdsoft_autocomplete" style="display: inline-block; width: 170px;">` - есть атрибуты `class` и `style`, но ищите вы по `id` - сильно!

2. Вы используете функцию `contains(string, string)` имеющую две строковые переменные, но объявляете в ней только одну - `contains(@class='nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input')`, и ждёте что она что-то вернёт.
3. Зачем использовать contains(str, str) если вы можете найти элемент по указателю на атрибут - @class='nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input' - такой указатель найдёт элемент у которого `class` равен  значению `nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input`.

В зависимости от того, как вы хотите найти ваш элемент `input`, можно набросать парочку вариантов XPath которые будут в разной степени "свободны":

1. `//*[@class="nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input"]` - найдёт все элементы у которых `class` равен `nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input`
2. `//input[@class="nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input"]` - то же что и верхний, но будет искать только `input` элементы
3. `//div/input[@class="nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input"]` - то же что и верхних два, но теперь ищет последовательность `div/input`
4. `//div[@class="xdsoft_autocomplete"]/input[@class="nostyle str_obj xdsoft_input"]` - то же что и верхних три, но теперь будет искать точные значения выбранных атрибутов (`class` и `class`) в последовательности `div/input` - **этот** максимально похож на тот, что хотели написать вы.